What is the difference between these 2 queries?
(sale_id, year) is the primary key (combination of columns with unique values) of this table.
product_id is a foreign key (reference column) to Product table.
Each row of this table shows a sale on the product product_id in a certain year.
QUERY 1:
SELECT
    product_id,
    MIN(year) first_year,
    quantity,
    price
FROM 
    sales
GROUP BY
    product_id


QUERY 2:
select 
    product_id, 
    year as first_year, 
    quantity, 
    price
from 
    Sales
where
    (product_id, year) in (
                            select 
                                product_id, 
                                min(year) 
                            from 
                                Sales
                            group by 
                                product_id
                            )

This is from a problem in LeetCode, my solution is Query#1 (it did not work), however, Query#2 seems to work but I cannot understand what the difference between the two is

you have to group by everything that is not an aggregate. that is why your first query is giving an error.

Your first query is invalid as it is not ANSI SQL.  While it might run on your MySQL tool, such syntax should never be used.  Here is a corrected version using proper joins to restrict each product to the record from the earliest year:
SELECT s1.product_id, s1.year AS first_year, s1.quantity, s1.price
FROM sales s1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT product_id, MIN(year) AS first_year
    FROM sales
    GROUP BY product_id
) s2
    ON s2.product_id = s1.product_id AND
       s2.first_year = s1.year;


I see a lot of answers like this rather than explain why this works on MySQL , just add a simple should never be used. Would be better to mention that this functionality is controlled by the sql_mode only_full_group_by. As per it is not ANSI SQL, MySQL not always depends on  ANSI SQL.  I agree that this should never be used because of the arbitrary data

@ErgestBasha In fact I just finished a 6 month long project at work to refactor MySQL code to allow enabling the ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY flag.  I saw some of the worst technical MySQL debt I have ever seen.

as mentioned in my comment you must group by everything that is not an aggregate.  so if you don't want to do that but instead want to show all rows where the first year by product id matches then you can use the second query or what I prefer to do is use a windowing function like dense_rank
so assign a ranking to each year partitioned by the product id and then pick the ones where the ranking is 1.
WITH RankedSales AS (
    SELECT
        product_id,
        year AS first_year,
        quantity,
        price,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY product_id ORDER BY year) AS rnk
    FROM
        Sales
)
SELECT
    product_id,
    first_year,
    quantity,
    price
FROM
    RankedSales
WHERE
    rnk = 1;


Wouldn't doing it this way make the query considerably slower?

MySQL 8.0 introduced window functions, and the optimizer has been improving but probably not as well as some other RDMSs. so a traditional inner join will probably have the edge in performance. but I'm just guessing. best would be to run both versions and check the execution plan and timing.

Yeah, I just checked, inner join works better, but this is an interesting take on the problem as well :)

In query 2 you used Sub query method
Subquery: It uses a subquery to find the minimum year for each product. This subquery groups the sales table by product_id and then uses MIN(year) to find the earliest year for each product.
Main Query: The main query then filters the original sales table. It checks if the combination of product_id and year from the sales table exists in the results of the subquery. This effectively selects only the rows where the year is the minimum year (first year) for that product.
